# tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img cannot import grayscale images directly without clipping error

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib

This beach [image: This beach] can be properly imported, resized and displayed with this code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
img_rows, img_cols = 32, 32
imgTest = load_img('beach.png', color_mode='grayscale', target_size=(img_rows, img_cols))
imgTest = img_to_array(imgTest) #returns a 3d numpy array
print(imgTest.shape)
imgTest=imgTest.squeeze()
plt.imshow(imgTest)
```

The numpy array has dimensions (32,32,1) so I have to drop the third dimension for it to properly display and that is why I use `imgTest=imgTest.squeeze()`

But the output is colorful even tho I converted to grayscale and my array is only 32x32 of luminance values. I would have thought the grayscale conversion would have remained gray.

[image]

Why are colors being shown?

If I use a grayscale image to start with like this one:

[image: graybeach]

I get the same greenish 32x32 image.
The array given by load_img has single luminance values, so where do the colors come from?

If I load the grayscale image WITHOUT grayscale conversion using:

```
imgTest = load_img('beachGRAY.png', target_size=(img_rows, img_cols))
```

and of course omit the squeeze statement because my array has RGB values, I get this warning:

```
Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).
```

and a blank plot. Why is my plot blank? When I look at `print(imgTest[0:2])` There are numbers in there <255 so something should show. No?

Comment: I had a similar issue. I have realised that I need to pass cmap='gray' as second parameter in imshow.